# merge 2 query results in one in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am getting 2 query results like this :

```
$youtube = new Youtube();

    $videos = $youtube->search($term, $max_result, $start_index);

    $result_y = self::batch_create($videos['videos']);

    //return $result;
    $dailymotion = new Dailymotion;

    $videos =  $dailymotion->search($term, $max_result, $start_index);

     $result_d = self::batch_create($videos['videos']);
```

now i am trying to merge them into one query results 
this is how result_y and result_d are http://laravel.io/bin/GdBbm#

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$final_result = (object) array_merge((array) $result_y, (array) $result_d);
```

First we are casting both Video objects **$result_y** and **$result_d** to an array then merging them using array_merge and then again casting them back to an object.